# SQL Server function errors trying to run. Throws conversion failed error

Tags: sql-server, function

I'm not sure why I am getting a conversion issues when executing my function.  I don't seem to see where I'm trying to convert from `nvarchar` to int anywhere.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Sample_Position]('D84: 0.5 Hr PD')
```

I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0.5' to data type int.

This is my complete code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Sample_Position] 
    (@field nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS @tbl TABLE 
             (
                 POS_ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
                 POS_Type  nvarchar(100),
                 POS_Sort1 nvarchar(100),
                 POS_Sort2 nvarchar(100),
                 POS_Sort3 nvarchar(100)
             ) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pos_Type  nvarchar(4000),
            @pos_Sort1 nvarchar(4000),
            @pos_Sort2 nvarchar(4000),
            @pos_Sort3 nvarchar(4000)
    
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @pos_Type = CASE   
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 1) = 'D' THEN 'Day'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 1) = 'W' THEN 'Week'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 2) = 'GD' THEN 'Gestation Day'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'PND' THEN 'Prenatal Day'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'PPD' THEN 'Post Partum Day'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 2) = 'BD' THEN 'Birth Day'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'Phy' THEN 'Physical'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 4) = 'UNSC' THEN 'Unscheduled'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 5) = 'PreTx' THEN 'Pre Treatment'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'Imm' THEN 'Immediate'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'EOI' THEN 'End of Infusion'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'SOI' THEN 'Start of Infusion'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'KLH' THEN 'Key Lymphoid'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 4) = 'KLHC' THEN 'Key Lymphoid Challenge'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 4) = 'PKLH' THEN 'Pre Key Lymphoid'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'TTC' THEN 'Tetinus Toxoid'
                            WHEN LEFT(@field, 4) = 'PTTC' THEN 'Pre-Tetinus Toxoid'
                            ELSE @field
                        END
          
        SELECT @pos_Sort1 = CASE
                        WHEN @pos_Type = 'Day' then SUBSTRING(@field, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @field), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @field + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @field) + 1)
                        ELSE 1
                        END
    
        SELECT @pos_Sort2 = CASE
                        WHEN @pos_Type = 'Day' then SUBSTRING(right(@field, len(@field)- PATINDEX('%[ ]%', @field)), PATINDEX('%[0-9.]%', right(@field, len(@field)- PATINDEX('%[ ]%', @field))), PATINDEX('%[0-9.][^0-9.]%', right(@field, len(@field)- PATINDEX('%[ ]%', @field)) + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9.]%', right(@field, len(@field)- PATINDEX('%[ ]%', @field))) + 1)
                        ELSE 2
                        END
    
        SELECT @pos_Sort3 = @field
          
        INSERT INTO @tbl (POS_Type, POS_Sort1, POS_Sort2, POS_Sort3)
        VALUES (@pos_Type, @pos_Sort1, @pos_Sort2, @pos_Sort3)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: Unrelated, but your datatypes don't match. For example `pos_Sort3` is 4000 bytes long as a variable, 100 in the table, and you equate it to `@field` which is `max`

Comment: Have you tried selecting those substrings on their own, outside the function?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's your sort variables evaluation. In your `Else` part you are returning integer value making SQL to think that return type should be integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, as mentioned, is that one side of your `CASE` is a `varchar`, the other an `int` or `numeric`. And `int` has a higher precedence, so the `varchar` is converted to `int` and fails.

You can get around this by just putting `1` and `2` into quotes `'1'` and `2'`. Alternatively, you can cast your substring expressions to `int`, but be careful, as that could fail, and it would be best to use `TRY_CAST`.

Aside from that, you are using a multi-statement Table Valued Function, which can be slow, especially when run in a correlated `APPLY`. Instead use an inline TVF.

This also shows how to use `CROSS APPLY` and virtual tables (`SELECT` with no `FROM`, or a `VALUES` table), and feed them on into the next.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Sample_Position
    (@field nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN

SELECT

  POS_ID = 1,

  v1.pos_Type,

  pos_Sort1 = CASE
              WHEN v1.pos_Type = 'Day' THEN
                   SUBSTRING(
                     @field,
                     v1.FirstDigit,
                     PATINDEX(
                       '%[0-9][^0-9]%',
                       @field + 't'
                     ) - v1.FirstDigit + 1
                   )
              ELSE
                  '1'
              END,
    
  pos_Sort2 = CASE
              WHEN v1.pos_Type = 'Day' THEN
                SUBSTRING(
                  v2.AfterSpace,
                  v3.DigitAfterSpace,
                  PATINDEX(
                    '%[0-9.][^0-9.]%',
                    v2.AfterSpace + 't'
                   ) - v3.DigitAfterSpace + 1
                )
              ELSE
               '2'
              END,

  pos_Sort3 = @field

FROM (
    SELECT
      pos_Type =
        CASE   
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 1) = 'D' THEN 'Day'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 1) = 'W' THEN 'Week'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 2) = 'GD' THEN 'Gestation Day'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'PND' THEN 'Prenatal Day'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'PPD' THEN 'Post Partum Day'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 2) = 'BD' THEN 'Birth Day'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'Phy' THEN 'Physical'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 4) = 'UNSC' THEN 'Unscheduled'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 5) = 'PreTx' THEN 'Pre Treatment'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'Imm' THEN 'Immediate'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'EOI' THEN 'End of Infusion'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'SOI' THEN 'Start of Infusion'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'KLH' THEN 'Key Lymphoid'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 4) = 'KLHC' THEN 'Key Lymphoid Challenge'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 4) = 'PKLH' THEN 'Pre Key Lymphoid'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 3) = 'TTC' THEN 'Tetinus Toxoid'
        WHEN LEFT(@field, 4) = 'PTTC' THEN 'Pre-Tetinus Toxoid'
        ELSE @field
        END,

    FirstDigit =
      PATINDEX(
        '%[0-9]%',
        @field
      ),

    FirstSpace =
      PATINDEX(
        '%[ ]%',
        @field
      )

) v1

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      AfterSpace =
        right(
          @field,
          len(@field) - v1.FirstSpace
        )
) v2

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      DigitAfterSpace =
        PATINDEX(
          '%[0-9.]%',
          v2.AfterSpace
        )
) v3
;
```

Comment: This works amazingly.   Its a bit humbling to see how much you don't know.   Going to take me a bit to understand how it functions behind the curtains.  However, I can't thank you enough.   Still in the learning phase of MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the statement below, you will see an output of '0.5' and then a conversion error.

```
PRINT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN '0.5' ELSE 1.5 END

PRINT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN '0.5' ELSE 1 END
```

This is because SQL Server is inferring the resulting data type based on the literal you coded into your statement.

To get around this return a string literal instead.

```
PRINT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN '0.5' ELSE '1' END
```

CASE statements return data based on data type precedence rules. All possible results are evaluated. The first statement above does not error out because all evaluated results are compatible. In the second statement, the last result can not be converted into the data type of the first possible result.